# Figure out what is the right solution. Pointers

Tags: c

What is the accessible value of `*p1` after using `procd3`?

```
void procd3(int *pt1, int *pt2){
    int *pt3;
    pt3 = pt1;
    pt1 = pt2;
    *pt1= *pt3 + 1;
}

    void main(){
    int va;
    int *p1, *p2;
    …
    p1=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    p2=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p1=3;
    …
    *p2= *p1 + 2;
    …
    procd3(p1,p2);
    …
}
```

I think that the answer is 4. Because `*p1=3`at the start and `*p2=*p1+2=5`. So when the function gets called `pt3=3`, then `pt1=5`, and finally `*pt1=3+1=4`.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Have you made an effort to solve it yourself?

Comment: Sheesh, or even just run it yourself and see?

Comment: @Louis You can `printf` to test it, you know..

Comment: @BlueMoon When I'm doing `pt3=pt1` what does that mean?

Comment: @Louis What do you think it could be? Just to clarify: Homework questions are fine. But you haven't shown what you tried and "explain this-wall-of-code" questions are not suitable for this site.

Comment: @BlueMoon Ok. Sorry for that. I have added some text to the post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can solve the problem yourself by either stepping through the code with a debugger, or adding some printfs.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of illustration, let's assume that `malloc` returns `0x1000` and `0x1004` for `p1` and `p2`.  So when you call `procd3`, `pt1` is initially `0x1000` and `pt2` is initially `0x1004`.

The first thing that happens is you assign the value of `pt1` to `pt3`, then you assign the value of `pt2` to `pt1`, giving us the following:

```
pt3 == 0x1000 == p1
pt1 == 0x1004 == p2

*pt3 == *p1 == 3
```

Now, you do the assignment

```
*pt1 = *pt3 + 1;
```

But remember, `pt1` is pointing to the same location as `p2` - `0x1004`.  The memory that `p1` points to is not affected.  So after the function call, `*p1` is still `3`.